# Using DeferAsync() and Followupasync() in a slash command causes bot to be unresponsive when in a container

Tags: discord, discord.net

I have a bot written in discord.net hosted inside a docker container. There is a simple slash command that queries a database as follows-

```
    [SlashCommand("getmoney", "get current total of currency for given user")]
    [DefaultPermission(true)]
    public async Task GetMoney(Discord.IUser user) 
    {
        var userHelper = new UserHelper(_dbContext);
        var userRecord = userHelper.FindOrAddUser(user.Id.ToString());

        await ReplyAsync($"{user.Username} has {userRecord.Funds} Dollars!");
    }
```

This works fine.

I then updated the command to use DeferAsync() and followupAsync()

```
[SlashCommand("getmoney", "get current total of currency for given user")]
[DefaultPermission(true)]
public async Task GetMoney(Discord.IUser user) 
{
    await DeferAsync();

    var userHelper = new UserHelper(_dbContext);
    var userRecord = userHelper.FindOrAddUser(user.Id.ToString());

    await FollowupAsync($"{user.Username} has {userRecord.Funds} Dollars!");
}
```

Which works fine running locally in debug. But when running in a container **all** slash commands now timeout, even ones in different module classes. There are no errors in the log file when a command is sent.

I tried rebuilding a new image from a commit before the change and hosting it in the same place and that works fine, which means something about this change is causing the issue without triggering any errors in logs.